# bool value does NOT get stored in core data stack

Tags: core-data

I'm trying to simply toggle a BOOL Attribute in my core data stack and also use that coredata bool to set the "state" of a UISwitch in viewDidLoad in my mainView.

following scenario:
Switch is off, user hits edit(save) UIButton, --> that toggles the settingSysTimeOverride Attribute of entity Setting from @NO to @YES
next time app launches, in viewDidLoad, I fetch the core data stack and look at status of settingSysTimeOverride and use that to
set the "state" of my UISwitch.

But for some reason, my value does NOT get stored to core data stack.
The whole project is attached, also here is my code.

[image: Screen Shot 2014-06-12 at 22.27.28.png]

MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *settingsArray;
@end


@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize editSetting;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext

{
    return [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]managedObjectContext];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Setting" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"settingSysTimeOverride == %@", editSetting];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR! %@ - %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"FETCH SUCCESSFUL");
    }

    if ((fetchedObjects.count) >0) {
        // list array contents
        for (int i=0; i < (fetchedObjects.count); i++) {

            // output for debug purpose

            NSLog(@"Array-index [%i]: %@", i, fetchedObjects[i]);
        }
    }

    // check settingSysTimeOverride and set UISwitch-State
    if (editSetting.settingSysTimeOverride.boolValue == 0) {
        // turn switch to OFF - Position
        _overrideSysTimeSwitch.on = NO;
    } else {
        // turn switch to ON - Position
        _overrideSysTimeSwitch.on = YES;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)editSave:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender

{
    // toggle BOOL status of settingSysTimeOverride here
    //
}

- (IBAction)overrideSysTime:(UISwitch *)sender
{
}

- (IBAction)timeFormat:(UISwitch *)sender {
}
@end




MainViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "Setting.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong)Setting *editSetting;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *editSaveButton

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *overrideSysTimeLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeFormatLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *overrideSysTimeSwitch;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *timeFormatSwitch;


- (IBAction)editSave:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
- (IBAction)overrideSysTime:(UISwitch *)sender;
- (IBAction)timeFormat:(UISwitch *)sender;
@end



AppDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

Setting.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Setting : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * settingName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * settingSysTimeOverride;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * settingTimeFormat;
@end





Setting.m
#import "Setting.h"

@implementation Setting
@dynamic settingName;
@dynamic settingSysTimeOverride;
@dynamic settingTimeFormat;

@end
```

Can someone please help me with this???

Answer (score 0):

here is what I was doing wrong, I hope it's going to help others in the future to avoid running in the same issues:

I forgot to point my NSManagedObject at the beginning of my fetched array.

```
NSManagedObject *matches;
matches=[objects objectAtIndex:(0)];
```

The code in one piece would look like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context;
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc;
NSFetchRequest *request;

NSPredicate *pred;
NSManagedObject *matches;

NSArray *objects;

NSUInteger elementsInArray;

context = [self managedObjectContext];
entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Setting" inManagedObjectContext:context];
pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(settingName = %@)", @"User-Settings"];

request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];
[request setPredicate:pred];

matches = nil;
NSError *errorFS = nil;

if (!(objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&errorFS])) {
    // fetch failed
    NSLog(@"Fetch failed: %@ - %@", [errorFS localizedDescription], [errorFS userInfo]);
} else {
    // fetch succeeded
    NSLog(@"Fetch Succeeded");
}

if ([objects count] == 0)
{   // does not exist -> error?
} else
{
   matches=[objects objectAtIndex:(0)];  // <- HERE WAS THE ERROR !!!!!
   // # system time override switch
   if([[matches valueForKey:@"settingSysTimeOverride"] boolValue]) {
   _sysTimeOverrideSwitch.on = YES;
} else {
   _sysTimeOverrideSwitch.on = NO;
}

}
```